# Watch is not working in VSCode, howto fix?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, watch

Some time ago a Watch window stop working in Visual Studio Code. I am using VsCode for Powershell only. [Powershell is only one extension that is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i3Qz.jpg). [However, I can see variables in Variables->Auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYICa.jpg) and  [when I put the mouse cursor on the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voxKl.jpg). Windows with all updates and VScode is the latest version. Pressing "+" in the watch window sometimes allows adding variables sometimes not, but in all cases, the value is empty.
P.S. Start VCsode with local admin rights didn't help.

Comment: Did it happened after you upgraded VSCode?

Comment: @Dennis I am not sure. It is possible that it happened after the upgrade.

Comment: Some extensions stop working with newer versions of VS Code (and the other way around).

Comment: I have only one extension which is Powershell from Microsoft